# How do I import, instead of open, files for a NSDocument-based app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, import, nsdocument

I'm a newbie trying out a web-browser app, using WebKit with the NSDocument architecture (as in some of the WebKit reference code).  I have it opening a pre-set home page, then post the current URL to an adjacent text field, then have the WebView open an URL entered into the text field, and then I changed it to load in local files.  I did that using the existing NSDocument file-opening code: I override the URL and NSData opening methods to cache both of those (inside the document object), then at XIB-creation time I pass those attributes to the WebView.

It seems to work, but there's been weirdness.  I've been trying to work around it, but I think I need a re-think.  I finally realized that the local file is still the flagged by the NSDocument architecture even when I change the web page (with the text field) away from the local file.  I think I need to "import" the local file instead of "open."  One way is to de-certify the file from internal tracking after loading it.  The other way is to do a non-tracking read to begin with.  Which way is best?  And how can I do it in the NSDocument architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after posting this, I found out that `NSDocument` has the `fileURL` and `setFileURL:` methods, which control the property of what file the document object is tracking.  It can be deliberately set to `nil` to de-certify the document's current file.

Of course, now exporting uses "Untitled" as the base file for saving the current browser page.  The window gets its title from a Cocoa Binding to the WebView's page title property, but that doesn't carry over to the document object.  I'll see how to fix that....

Answer (score 0):

To change the default "Untitled" to something sensible, use NSDocuments setDisplayName method. (Curiously in swift, the displayName is a read-only property but the method .setDisplayName() is available and does the trick (XCode 7.3.1).)